# possible bug: shr-render-buffer is not preserving URLs

Tags: html, email, url, shr

Running `shr-render-buffer` renders the HTML accurately using appropriate faces for different element types and underlines links but clicking on any of the links produces the message:

*No link under point.*

Any suggestions?

GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2022-10-11

Comment: Works fine here. Did you try starting with `emacs -q`? If that works, your init file is at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `eww` instead of `shr` with this function works:

```
(defun eww-render-current-buffer ()
  "Render HTML in the current buffer with EWW"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (eww-display-html 'utf8 nil nil nil (current-buffer)))
```